# A strongly pseudomonotone map that is not strongly monotone

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples, monotone-functions

Let $K$ be a closed convex subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F: K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. We say that

- $F$ is strongly monotone on $K$ if there exists $\gamma>0$ such that
  $$
  \left<F(y)-F(x), y-x\right>\geq \gamma\|y-x\|^2, \quad \forall x,y\in K.
  $$
- $F$ is strongly pseudomonotone on $K$ if there exists $\gamma>0$ such that
  $$
  \left<F(x), y-x\right>\geq 0 \Longrightarrow \left<F(y), y-x\right>\geq \gamma\|y-x\|^2
  $$
  for all $x,y\in K$.

It is easily to verify that strongly monotone implies strongly pseudomonotone.
The converse is not true in general. For example, in one-dimensional case 
$$
F(x)=(2-x), \quad K=[0,1],
$$ 
the mapping $F$ is strongly pseudomonotone but not strongly monotone on $K$.

**Question:** Can we find a mapping $F: K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n (n\geq 2)$ such that $F$ is strongly pseudomonotone but not strongly monotone on $K$. It is interesting to find an affine mapping as in the above example.

Comment: Presumably you want $K$ to have nonempty interior, otherwise just transfer the one-dimensional example to a line segment in ${\mathbb R}^n$.

Comment: With that assumption, if $F$ is affine, i.e. $F(x) = c + Tx$ where $T$ is linear, then $F$ is strongly monotone iff there is no nonzero vector $v$ with $\langle T v, v \rangle \le 0$. The question then is whether $F$ can be strongly pseudomonotone if such a vector exists.  I don't know the answer.

Comment: @Robert Israel: Dear Sir. I am confess that I would like to find an example in $\mathbb{R}^n (n\geq 2)$ and $\text{int}K\ne \emptyset$ (K has a nonempty interior). Do you have any comments on my problem. Thank you for your helping and your consideration on my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give two examples: affine and non-affine. The non-affine is nice and easy to understand. The affine is a pain to write out in details, but I give the idea.

**Non-affine example.** I define it on the punctured unit ball $U=\{x\in \mathbb R^n : 0<\|x\|\le 1\}$; of course you can restrict it to a convex set. The definition is similar to yours: $F(x)=(2\|x\|^{-1}-1)x$. Clearly, this map is not monotone. To check strong pseudo-monotonicity, suppose  $\langle F(x),y-x\rangle \ge 0$. Then $\langle x,y-x\rangle \ge 0$. It follows that $$\langle F(y),y-x\rangle = (2\|y\|^{-1}-1)\langle y,y-x\rangle \ge (2\|y\|^{-1}-1)\langle y-x,y-x \rangle \ge \|y-x\|^2 $$
as required.

**Affine example.** I give it in two dimensions: you can make it work in higher dimensions by adding a small multiple of identity to the planar map. In complex notation, $F(z)=1+z+\frac34(1-i)\bar z$. This is not monotone: in terms of $z=x+iy$ we have 
$$G(z):=\mathrm{Re}\,((F(z)-F(0))(\bar z-0))=|z|^2+\frac34 \mathrm{Re}\,((1-i)\bar z^2) = \frac74x^2+\frac14y^2-\frac32xy$$ 
which is a indefinite quadratic form. It is negative precisely in the narrow sectors between the lines $y=(3\pm \sqrt{2})x$.

Let $U=\{z:|z|<r\}$ where $r>0$ is small enough for what follows. We must show that for all $z\in U$ and all $\zeta$ such that $\mathrm{Re}\,(F(z)\bar \zeta)\ge 0$ and $|\zeta|\le 2r$ the inequality $\mathrm{Re}\,(F(z)\bar \zeta)+G(\zeta)>0$ holds (we get $\ge \gamma |\zeta|^2$ by compactness and homogeneity). Clearly, we only have to worry about $\zeta$ in the aforementioned narrow sectors.

Actually, there is nothing to worry about when $\zeta $ is in the 1st quadrant sector $(3-\sqrt{2})x\le y\le (3+\sqrt{2})x$, $x>0$, because here the linear term  $\mathrm{Re}\,(F(z)\bar \zeta)$ is positive and dominates everything quadratic. As for the opposite 3rd quadrant sector, $\zeta$ is forbidden from it by the condition $\mathrm{Re}\,(F(z)\bar \zeta)\ge 0$, because $F(z)\approx 1$ when  $r$ is small.

Comment: Dir Sir. Thank you very much for your answer. I would like to discuss about your frist example (nonlinear case). Indeed, the mapping $F(u)=(2-\|u\|)u$ is **monotone** on the punctered unit ball $U$. Let $u,v\in U$, we note that $$

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*} \langle F(u)-F(v), u-v\rangle &=&\langle(2-\|u\|)u-(2-\|v\|)v, u-v\rangle\\ &=&\langle 2(u-v)-\|u\|(u-v)-v(\|u\|-\|v\|), u-v\rangle\\ &=&2\|u-v\|^2-\|u\|\|u-v\|^2-(\|u\|-\|v\|)\langle v, u-v\rangle\\ &\geq& 2\|u-v\|^2-\|u\|\|u-v\|^2-\left|\|u\|-\|v\|\right|\|v\|\|u-v\|\\ &\geq& 2\|u-v\|^2-\|u\|\|u-v\|^2-\|u-v\||\|v\|\|u-v\|\\ &\geq&0. \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @blindman I fixed it now. The example is obtained by vectorizing the scalar function $y=2-x$, but I forgot that multiplying $2-\|x\|$ by the vector $x$ changes the magnitide, not just direction.